# Do I need a UK visa if I have a 7-hour layover in London?

Tags: visas, transit, london, south-african-citizens

I’m a South African travelling from the USA to South Africa via London. Will I need a visa or something even if I don’t go out of the airport?

Answer (score 1):

With a South African passport, coming from the US, this is what you [would find](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa):

> You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit (unless you’re exempt)
>
> You should apply for a Direct Airside Transit visa if you arrive in the UK on a flight and leave again without passing through immigration control.
>
> Exemptions:
>
> You won’t need a visa if you:
>
> - are travelling to Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid
>   visa for that country
> - are travelling from Canada, New Zealand or the USA and it’s less than 6 months since you last entered that country with a valid
>   entry visa

So, when did you last travel to the US? What your US visa valid at the time?
If the time is 6 months or less and it was a valid visa, you're fine. Anything else, get a DATV.